# Why is tracking code generated for my site different than what is in the documentation?

Tags: google-analytics

Looking at the GA developers page at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide it says the tracking code is:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
```

But when I start an account for my site GA gives me the tracking code:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Why are these completely different?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet is for the old/traditional Google Analytics tracking script.

The second one uses the newer universal Google Analytics tracking script.

The reason why they are different is probably because Google is trying to push the newer tracking script, but haven't updated all of their documentation.

> The analytics.js JavaScript library is built on Universal Analytics technology. If you’re using a tracking code snippet on your website that references analytics.js, you’re using Universal Analytics.
>
> If you’re using any other library, like ga.js, you’re using a Classic Analytics tracking technology, and should upgrade your tracking code (if you also have a Universal Analytics property).

[Reference](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/4457764?hl=en)

Comment: OK. Great!  Could you point me, possibly, to the new code to generate an event for a button click?

Comment: [Here's the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events)

`ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, value);`