# Which tracking code am I supposed to use? The one with window.dataLayer or window.ga?

Tags: google-analytics

I've just started using GA (after I took a long vacation from it). It seems I'm missing something obvious/simple here.

I don't understand why in my analytics account / admin / property / tracking code they tell me to put this into `<header>` :

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-my-tracking-code-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-blahblah-1');
</script>
```

While in their docs they tell me to use this:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
window.ga=window.ga||function(){(ga.q=ga.q||[]).push(arguments)};ga.l=+new Date;
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<script async src='https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js'></script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Src: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/#the_javascript_tracking_snippet

These are completely different scripts o.O Additionally, the examples here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/how-analyticsjs-works just don't work with the first snippet, because `ga` is undefined.

Is this because they have different API versions? Then... why isn't this explained somewhere o.O

I'm asking because I get

> unreachable code after return statement

In the console, on this javascript: https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-my-tracking-code-1:formatted

I also found this answer:

[Why is tracking code generated for my site different than what is in the documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617001/why-is-tracking-code-generated-for-my-site-different-than-what-is-in-the-documen)

But it's from 2015, and the js snippets are again different, so I guess I can't use it as a reference.

All of this is just weird, this is why there are so many "o.O" in my question, please forgive me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely slightly confusing, but you're seeing the difference between analytics.js and gtag.js. You can learn more about the differences between them and/or migrating to gtag.js [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/migration).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! For all the other lost, shocked, misguided, terrified people coming here from google search or something, the very first result in google for "google analytics tutorial" is **obsolete** and google just forgot to put this big red warning message box at the top, saying "Hello there! This is **old**, don't waste your precious time here! You probably want https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/ !"  Well, it happens, does it... Anyway - thanks again, Mark! :)